# Making mass/bulk update by attribute value in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute, update

I have feature class with 70,000+ records (file geodatabase). 
I want to make in bulk update on an attribute where the value is NULL.
Select by attribute shows that I have 5,000 records like that. Doing it one by one is going to be a pain.

In sql pseudo code it should be something like that:

```
 UPDATE <MyAttributeName> = 'NewValue'
 WHERE <MyAttributeName> IS NULL
```

How do I do that with ArcMap 10.1?

Comment: Wouldn't a simple field calculation expression solve this easily? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I did some t-sql scripting for a regular (non-GIS) database for the last 2 weeks, so my brain is still firing t-sql :) sorry. Need some time to switch back to ArcGIS way of manipulating data...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would select the rows which are NULL (sounds like you have done that) then simply run the [calculate field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000) tool.

Right Click the field you want to modify (while objects are selected)
[image: field calc1]

Then input your value "newvalue"
[image: fieldcalc2]
NOTE: 1. if you don't have a selection this will work on "ALL" rows in your table!
2. Double quotes in this area on your text/date value. [See esri help for examples of vba/python/string/number/codeblock options](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/0017/001700000046000000.htm)
3. Must begin edit session to run in FGDB.

Answer (score 4):

May be an overkill, but I tried Python with the Field Calculator:

[image: Python script check for NULL values]