# Using Field Calculator with Python Parser and if/elif statements in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have tried all of below snippets to use Python Parser in Field Calculator and update the values of a field called `type` based on a filed called `MamerMN` but in all of them I am getting Syntax error in Geoprocessing result window!

```
if !MamerMN! <= 0.151560:
    return 1
```

and

```
if (!MamerMN! <= 0.151560):
    return 1
```

and

```
if (MamerMN <= 0.151560):
    return 1
```

and

```
def(MamerMN)
if MamerMN <= 0.151560:
    return 1
```

and

```
def(MamerMN)
if (MamerMN <= 0.151560):
    return 1
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

**Update**

```
def foo(MamerMN):
  if MamerMN <= 0.151560:
     return 1
```

Comment: did you push the python radio button?

Comment: Are you placing this in the codeblock? You need to make sure you're using proper indentation as well. The last two are not proper python syntax either. it should be `def foo(bar): return bar**bar`

Comment: Yes Brad , I already did

Comment: @Paul , can you please let me know what do you mean by codeblock?

Comment: [Here's](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/70440/19311) one of the first examples I found.

Comment: @Paul, Can you please take a look at Update code? I am using exactly what you have said and based on the example but st getting error!

Comment: Ok, so if that is your code block then the expression should look like `foo(!MamerMN!)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27115/discussion-between-behseini-and-paul).

Comment: There are many earlier duplicates for this one, another is http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99615/writing-conditional-if-then-statements-into-field-calculator-of-arcgis-for-des

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Paul](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/19311/paul)

Here is the solution:
in Pre-logic Script Code Box:

```
def foo(MamerMN): 
  if (MamerMN <= 0.200000): 
     return 1
  elif (MamerMN >= 0.200001 and  MamerMN <= 0.400000):
     return 2
  elif (MamerMN >= 0.400001 and  MamerMN <= 0.600000):
     return 3
  elif (MamerMN >= 0.600001 and  MamerMN <= 0.800000):
     return 4
  elif (MamerMN >= 0.800001):
     return 5
```

and in Expression box

```
foo( !MamerMN! )
```